# Why does @GetMapping have a 'consumes' attribute?

Tags: java, spring-rest

In spring framework, @GetMapping doesn't have a body. But it has a 'consumes' attribute. So how does it use this attribute without a body?

example:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/methodA", consumes = "application/json")
```

Comment: you can send GET with body https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: If you specify consumes application/json on a GetRequest and then call the controller from a testresttemplate or webtestclient it will always throw unspported http 415.

Answer (score 1):

You can read queryParam/Request HTTP header as below:

```
@GetMapping(value = "{URL}")
public ResponseEntity getMethod(@RequestParam("consumes") String consumes) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this was not what I meant. I added an example to the question to be more clear.